# How to select column from from DATAFRAME with condition

Tags: python, pandas

**Spreadsheet**

```py
DATE_ID Site    RRC_Fail#   S1_Fail#    pmCellDowntimeAuto
27-07-2021 03   S1  0   0   2
27-07-2021 03   S2  0   0   900
27-07-2021 03   S3  0   0   900
27-07-2021 03   S4  0   0   900
27-07-2021 03   S5  0   0   2
27-07-2021 03   S6  0   0   2
27-07-2021 03   S7  1   1   26
27-07-2021 03   S8  0   0   4
27-07-2021 03   S9  0   0   1800
27-07-2021 03   S10 0   0   5
27-07-2021 03   S11 0   0   1800
27-07-2021 03   S12 0   0   2
27-07-2021 03   S13 0   0   25
27-07-2021 03   S14 0   0   900
27-07-2021 03   S15 0   0   900
```

***Expected Output:-***

```py
DATE_ID Site    RRC_Fail#   S1_Fail#    pmCellDowntimeAuto
27-07-2021 03   S2  0   0   900
27-07-2021 03   S3  0   0   900
27-07-2021 03   S4  0   0   900
27-07-2021 03   S9  0   0   1800
27-07-2021 03   S11 0   0   1800
27-07-2021 03   S14 0   0   900
27-07-2021 03   S15 0   0   900
```

CODE:-

```
import pandas as pd


df=pd.read_csv("test.csv", index_col=("DATE_ID"), names =['DATE_ID','Site','Zone','Status_AOL','ERBS','EUtranCellFDD','RRC_Fail#','RRC_Failure_Rate%','S1_Fail#','S1_Failure_Rate%','Downtime'], header=0 )
df2 = df.loc(['Zone == West'] | df['Downtime']>50)

df2.plot.bar(color = 'blue')
print(df2)
```

Error:-

File "pandas_libs\ops.pyx", line 233, in pandas._libs.ops.vec_binop

ValueError: Arrays were different lengths: 30 vs 1

Comment: Can you give the condition clearly, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input dataframe:

```
>>> df
            DATE_ID Site   Zone  RRC_Fail#  S1_Fail#  pmCellDowntimeAuto
27-07-2021        3   S1   East          0         0                   2
27-07-2021        3   S2   East          0         0                 900
27-07-2021        3   S3   East          0         0                 900
27-07-2021        3   S4   East          0         0                 900
27-07-2021        3   S5  North          0         0                   2
27-07-2021        3   S6   East          0         0                   2
27-07-2021        3   S7  North          1         1                  26
27-07-2021        3   S8  North          0         0                   4
27-07-2021        3   S9   East          0         0                1800
27-07-2021        3  S10  North          0         0                   5
27-07-2021        3  S11   East          0         0                1800
27-07-2021        3  S12   East          0         0                   2
27-07-2021        3  S13   West          0         0                  25
27-07-2021        3  S14   East          0         0                 900
27-07-2021        3  S15   East          0         0                 900
```

Select rows that match your conditions:

```
>>> df.loc[(df['Zone'] == 'West') | (df['pmCellDowntimeAuto'] > 50)]
            DATE_ID Site  Zone  RRC_Fail#  S1_Fail#  pmCellDowntimeAuto
27-07-2021        3   S2  East          0         0                 900
27-07-2021        3   S3  East          0         0                 900
27-07-2021        3   S4  East          0         0                 900
27-07-2021        3   S9  East          0         0                1800
27-07-2021        3  S11  East          0         0                1800
27-07-2021        3  S13  West          0         0                  25
27-07-2021        3  S14  East          0         0                 900
27-07-2021        3  S15  East          0         0                 900
```

---

**Old answer**
Your code and your input sample do not match.

If your condition is Zone is west or Downtime is greater than 50 then:

```
df2 = df.loc[(df['Zone'] == 'West') | (df['Downtime'] > 50)]
```

If your condition is pmCellDowntimeAuto is greater than or equal to 900:

```
>>> df.loc[df['pmCellDowntimeAuto'] >= 900]
            DATE_ID Site  RRC_Fail#  S1_Fail#  pmCellDowntimeAuto
27-07-2021        3   S2          0         0                 900
27-07-2021        3   S3          0         0                 900
27-07-2021        3   S4          0         0                 900
27-07-2021        3   S9          0         0                1800
27-07-2021        3  S11          0         0                1800
27-07-2021        3  S14          0         0                 900
27-07-2021        3  S15          0         0                 900
```

Comment: I want to select Site , RRC fail where zone = west & pmCellDowntimeAuto> 900. I try to select only site & RRC fail coloumn for above condition.

Comment: You can refer this spreadsheet.DATE_ID Site Zone RRC_Fail# S1_Fail# pmCellDowntimeAuto
27-07-2021 03 S1 East 0 0 2
27-07-2021 03 S2 East 0 0 900
27-07-2021 03 S3 East 0 0 900
27-07-2021 03 S4 East 0 0 900
27-07-2021 03 S5 North 0 0 2
27-07-2021 03 S6 East 0 0 2
27-07-2021 03 S7 North 1 1 26
27-07-2021 03 S8 North 0 0 4
27-07-2021 03 S9 East 0 0 1800
27-07-2021 03 S10 North 0 0 5
27-07-2021 03 S11 East 0 0 1800
27-07-2021 03 S12 East 0 0 2
27-07-2021 03 S13 West 0 0 25
27-07-2021 03 S14 East 0 0 900
27-07-2021 03 S15 East 0 0 900

Comment: @Debayannew. I updated my answer with your new dataset and correct the mistake on your conditions.